# MithrilJS passing variables to config on m() call

Tags: jquery, mithril.js

I'm trying to get the jQuery FooTable plugin working in my mithril app. I've got a config call like so in my component:

```
view: function(ctrl, args) {
  return m("table#globalConfigTable", {config: execFooTable})
}

this.execFooTable = function(element, isInit, context) {
  $('#globalConfigTable').footable({
    "columns": columns(),
    "rows": args.configRows
  })
}
```

args.configRows is my promise returned from my GET request that I'm passing to this component. I can see that it does successfully call my execFooTable function, but I can't seem to figure out how to access my args.configRows variable. I've tried context.configRows, and a bunch of other things, but they all come back as undefined.

Can anyone please help me out? Thank you.

Comment: The way you have declared the execFooTable it doesn't have access to the args variable because it's out of its scope. If you move create it instead inside the view function it should be able to access args.

Comment: Also use the `isInit` parameter to avoid calling the plugin more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function bellow:

```
// Partially apply arguments to a function. Useful for binding
// specific data to an event handler.
// Example use:
//
//   var add = function (x,y) { return x + y; }
//   var add5 = add.papp(5)
//   add5(7) //=> 11
//
Function.prototype.papp = function () {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        fn = this,
        args = slice.call(arguments);
        return function () {
            fn.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
        }
}
```

Then you can rewrite your code like this:

```
view: function(ctrl, args) {
  return m("table#globalConfigTable", {config: execFooTable.papp(args)})
}

this.execFooTable = function(args, element, isInit, context) {
  $('#globalConfigTable').footable({
    "columns": columns(),
    "rows": args.configRows
  })
}
```